# Update or create nested jsonb value using single update command

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Let us say I have [in Postgres **9.6**] a JSONB column named `xyz`. In an update, I want to set the `.foo.bar` key of this column to `{"done":true}`.

But the update must tolerate that the pre-update value for `xyz` is anything from `{}` to

```
{ 
    "abc": "Hello"
}
```

or maybe

```
{ 
    "foo": {
        "baz": { "done": false }
    },
    "abc": "Hello"
}
```

So I cannot use `jsonb_set` straight away, because it fails if `xyz->foo` is undefined. In that case I could use `jsonb_insert`, but that fails if `xyz->foo` **is** already defined.

So I try to use concatenation, with something like

```
jsonb_set( 
    jsonb_set(xyz, '{foo}', '{}'::jsonb || xyz->'foo', true),
    '{foo, bar}', '{"done":true}', true
)
```

...which also fails when `foo` is undefined since `xyz->'foo'` is `null` which overrides `{}` in the concatenation.

Obviously I could write a function that uses an `if` to get around this, but I really feel I should be able to do it in a single update.

Answer (score 42):

For this example:

```
{ 
    "foo": {
        "baz": { "done": false }
    },
    "abc": "Hello"
}
```

**INSERT:**

You have to use `jsonb_insert` you can test it with a `SELECT`.

```
SELECT jsonb_insert(xyz, '{foo,bar}', '{"done":true}'::jsonb) FROM tablename;
```

**Note:** With `jsonb_insert` is really important to set the path correctly. Here the path is '{foo:bar}' meaning that you will insert a JSON inside the object `foo` called `bar`.

Hence, the result is:

```
{
    "abc": "Hello",
    "foo": {
        "baz": {
            "done": false
        },
        "bar": {
            "done": true
        }
    }
}
```

**SET:**

To edit `bar` and set it to false you have to use `jsonb_set`. You can test it with `SELECT`:

```
SELECT jsonb_set(xyz, '{foo,bar}', '{"done":false}'::jsonb) FROM tablename;
```

This returns:

```
{
    "abc": "Hello",
    "foo": {
        "baz": {
            "done": false
        },
        "bar": {
            "done": false
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE FOR SET AND INSERT**

You use `jsonb_set` when the object exists and `jsonb_insert` when it doesn't. To update without knowing which one to use, you can use `CASE`

```
UPDATE tablename SET 
xyz= (CASE
        WHEN xyz->'foo' IS NOT NULL
        THEN jsonb_set(xyz, '{foo,bar}', '{"done":false}'::jsonb)
        WHEN xyz->'foo' IS NULL
        THEN jsonb_insert(xyz, '{foo}', '{"bar":{"done":true}}'::jsonb)
    END)
WHERE id=1;-- if you use an id to identify the JSON.
```

You can add some CASE clauses for more specific values.

Comment: Updated my answer, the last part has the answer you need. If I got your question right

Comment: The `UPDATE FOR SET AND INSERT` works with `{ }`, `{ "abc":"hello" }`, `{  "foo": { "baz": { "done": false }  }, "abc": "Hello" }`. And if there is bar `{ "foo": { "bar": { "done": true}  }}` it sets done to false.

Comment: Yes, that does work for the specific example I gave, so I give you 10 points ;-). Cumbersome to generalize, though, as the nesting goes deeper. For now I have resorted to doing it in Javascript...

Answer (score 1):

You can just use || to concatenate. It will overwrite or add any json value.

```
SELECT '{}'::jsonb || '{"foo":"bar"}'::jsonb
UPDATE tablename SET jdoc = jdoc || '{"foo":"bar"}'::jsonb
```

It's that easy.  I rarely use the functions in my software.

In the case of merging:

```
create or replace function jsonb_merge(orig jsonb, delta jsonb)
returns jsonb language sql as $$
    select
        jsonb_object_agg(
            coalesce(keyOrig, keyDelta),
            case
                when valOrig isnull then valDelta
                when valDelta isnull then valOrig
                when (jsonb_typeof(valOrig) <> 'object' or jsonb_typeof(valDelta) <> 'object') then valDelta
                else jsonb_merge(valOrig, valDelta)
            end
        )
    from jsonb_each(orig) e1(keyOrig, valOrig)
    full join jsonb_each(delta) e2(keyDelta, valDelta) on keyOrig = keyDelta
$$;
```

Comment: I am afraid not. For the case where `foo.baz` exists, just using concatenation will loose it: `select '{"foo":{"baz":123}}'::jsonb || '{"foo":{"bar":{"done":true}}}'::jsonb` yields only `{"foo":{"bar":{"done":true}}}` instead of the desired `{"foo":{"baz":123, "bar":{"done":true}}}`

Comment: I updated to include a merge function.  The first item is the original json, the second is the one you want to add.