# Add Nested Key Value to JSONB in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I am trying to append a key to a nested jsonb in postgres but I get errors.  Essentially I start with a json as:

```
{"tel": "123", "name": "foo", "new_info": {"a": "bar"}}
```

and I want to append `{"b", "baz"}` into "new_info" such that resulting jsonb is:

```
{"tel": "123", "name": "foo", "new_info": {"a": "bar", "b":"baz"}}
```

I am using the following commands to get to the original jsonb:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
 ID serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 data jsonb NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO mytable (data)
VALUES
 (
 '{ "name": "foo", "tel": "123"}'
 );

UPDATE mytable SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{new_info}', '{"a":"bar"}', TRUE) WHERE data @> '{"name": "foo"}' ;
```

and trying to use the following to update "new_info" which doesn't work:

```
WITH orig_new_info AS (SELECT data#>'{new_info}' FROM mytable WHERE data @> '{"name": "foo"}')
WITH updated_new_info AS (jsonb_set(orig_new_info, '{"b":"baz"}',TRUE ))
UPDATE mytable SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{new_info}', updated_new_info, TRUE) WHERE data @> '{"name": "foo"}';
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE #1:**

Per klins answer the following works:

```
update mytable 
set data = jsonb_insert(data, '{new_info}', data->'new_info' || '{"b":"baz"}', TRUE)
where data @> '{"name": "foo"}'
returning *;
```

However how can one avoid overwriting existing keys using something like jsonb_insert.  In other words why don't the following examples work?:

```
#ex 1
update mytable 
set data = jsonb_insert(data, '{new_info}', jsonb_insert(SELECT data->'new_info' FROM mytable WHERE data @> '{"name": "foo"}'), '{"b":"baz"}'),true)
where data @> '{"name": "foo"}'
returning *;

#ex2
WITH orig_new_info AS (SELECT data#>'{new_info}' FROM mytable WHERE data @> '{"name": "foo"}')
WITH updated_new_info AS(SELECT jsonb_insert(orig_new_info, orig_new_info ||'{"b":"bazer"}'))
update mytable 
set data = jsonb_set(data, '{new_info}', updated_new_info, TRUE)
where data @> '{"name": "foo"}'
returning *;
```

In other words klin's answer only considers the keys at the top level `data` jsonb as opposed to the keys of the nested `"new_info"` json that is inside of `data`.

**UPDATE #2:**

Per klins updated answer the following works:

```
update mytable 
set data = jsonb_insert(data, '{new_info, b}', '"baz"')
where data @> '{"name": "foo"}'
```

However if `"new_info"` doesn't exist in `data` the update completes successfully without saving.  Thus the following commands complete successfully but the data is not saved:

```
DROP TABLE mytable;

CREATE TABLE mytable (
 ID serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 data jsonb NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO mytable (data)
VALUES
 (
 '{ "name": "foo", "tel": "123"}'
 );

update mytable 
set data = jsonb_insert(data, '{new_info, b}', '"baz"')
where data @> '{"name": "foo"}'
returning *;
```

So this to me is a little surprising as it gives the impression that it saved although it didn't.  I want to avoid case statements as most of the time it will be a unnecessary check and would rather it fail if "new_info" doesn't exist (or just create it if it doesn't add overhead to situations where "new_info" does already exist). I.e I want to avoid what these answers do:

[Check if key exists in a JSON with PL/pgSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677057/check-if-key-exists-in-a-json-with-pl-pgsql/30733758)

[Update or create nested jsonb value using single update command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48888792/update-or-create-nested-jsonb-value-using-single-update-command)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `||` (concatenation operator):

```
update mytable 
set data = jsonb_set(data, '{new_info}', data->'new_info' || '{"b":"baz"}')
where data @> '{"name": "foo"}'
returning *

 id |                                data                                 
----+---------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {"tel": "123", "name": "foo", "new_info": {"a": "bar", "b": "baz"}}
(1 row)

UPDATE 1
```

---

The function `jsonb_set()` was introduced in Postgres 9.5. In Postgres 9.6+ you can also use `jsonb_insert(),` which may be more straightforward:

```
update mytable 
set data = jsonb_insert(data, '{new_info, b}', '"baz"')
where data @> '{"name": "foo"}'
```

From [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

> jsonb_insert(target jsonb, path text[], new_value jsonb, [insert_after boolean])
>
> (...) If *target* section designated by *path* is in JSONB object, *new_value* will be inserted only if *target* does not exist.

Hence *path* must point to non-existing key (the key you want to insert).

Comment: Thank you this works but how can I avoid overwriting existing key using something like jsonb_insert.  For example why doesn't this work:
WITH orig_new_info AS (SELECT data#>'{new_info}' FROM mytable WHERE data @> '{"name": "foo"}')
WITH updated_new_info AS(SELECT jsonb_set(orig_new_info, orig_new_info ||'{"b":"bazer"}',TRUE))
update mytable 
set data = jsonb_set(data, '{new_info}', updated_new_info, TRUE)
where data @> '{"name": "foo"}'
returning *;

Comment: see updated question.  Thanks very much for your answer

Comment: thanks much again! do you know why my examples don't work?  Is it not possible to manipulate data and new_info separately?  I have updated the question, the issue i am encountering is that if "new_info" doesn't exist the commands succeed without saving/updating???

Comment: The problem stems from that you want to do two different operations in a single function call. In the last your example the row **is updated** but the json value remains unchanged because `data->'new_info'` is null. Use `coalesce(),` it seems the simplest solution. See [DbFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=cd8a5b4bd5d1a0a2080f8c0b8ea01748)

Comment: Has anyone ever called you master?  Thanks, this is cool! But it seems that to do this with jsonb_insert would not be possible in one statement? Do you see any way to do this without overwriting existing values but still inserting "new_info" if it doesn't exist?  thank you again!